# How to access button elements within Vaadin confirm dialog?

Tags: vaadin

I want to set the focus on one of the buttons manually. What is the proper way to access these from within the Java class. I cannot see the button when I do

```
getElement().getChildren()...
```

When I inspect the dialog with the browser developer tools I can see the Element right there:

```
<vaadin-button theme="tertiary" slot="cancel-button" tabindex="0" role="button">Cancel</vaadin-button>
```

Thanks and Best Regads

Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use custom buttons there. See the example below. I create two buttons, the other being "Yes" button. I programmatically focus that when attached (i.e. Dialog has been opened). When you hit enter key, that will trigger "Yes" button, not the "No" button.

```
@Override
public void afterNavigation(AfterNavigationEvent event) {
    Button confirmButton = new Button("Yes");
    confirmButton.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.LUMO_PRIMARY);
    Button noButton = new Button("No");
    noButton.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.LUMO_TERTIARY);
    ConfirmDialog dialog = new ConfirmDialog();
    dialog.add("Confirm me");
    dialog.setCancelButton(confirmButton);
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    dialog.setConfirmButton(confirmButton);
    dialog.addConfirmListener(e -> Notification.show("Confirmed"));
    dialog.addCancelListener(e -> Notification.show("Cancelled"));
    dialog.open();
    confirmButton.addAttachListener(e -> confirmButton.focus());
}
```

Comment: This was added to my class that extends ConfirmDialog    

@Override
    public void setCancelable(boolean cancelable) {
        super.setCancelable(cancelable);
        cancelButton = new Button(getTranslation("Common.dialog.cancel"));
        cancelButton.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.LUMO_TERTIARY);
        cancelButton.addAttachListener(e -> cancelButton.focus());
        setCancelButton(cancelButton);
    }

But it does not seem to have any effect. I expect the dialogue to have the blue border around the cancel button, but there is nothing. Even if I set the autofocus property

Comment: Yes, but it is focused nevertheless.